# Impact, countable or uncountable?

Tags: sentence-choice, uncountable-nouns, countability

> This assumption has **a** negligible impact on the study.
>
> This assumption has negligible impact on the study.

Which one between the two above sentences is correct ?

Comment: They are both correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**a negligible impact** -- there is significant impact and insignificant impact; this one is of the insignificant or negligible variety

**negligible impact** -- there is either impact or no impact; we can speak of impact in terms of the *degree* of impact.